# Logo design: Use different logos for different media, or use the most simple one for all purposes?

Tags: logo, critique

I'm currently designing a logo for one of my projects (web application). It mainly deals with navigation and is named "navio".

I now have several options to choose from and realized that some that I like do not work when they should be used on a smaller scale (e.g. business card, website favicon, ...)

Should I use similar, but different logos for different types of media. Or should I stick with a very simple solution that works across the board?

Here are some of my options:

1. Most simple solution. Even works as a small favicon
   [image]
2. This was my initial idea. Is it confusing? Can you immediately differentiate the letters and understand that it spells the word "nav"?
   [image]
3. I like this a lot since it allows me to combine the main logo, complete name and web address... However I am not sure how well this will work for anything other than large poster prints.
   [image]

In general I like the idea that the logo includes the complete name, since it won't become a major brand which is commonly recognized and I am not sure if the puristic N will do... Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Just as a comment, mostly based on opinion but also trend based; I'm not a fan of the shading. It has not been on trend for the past few years and imo gives a logo an unprofessional or outdated look. I would suggest to research some recent logo design on sites like behance and dribbble. That being said, I do like the concept of this a lot. Although I doubt the www. works well on smaller screens and as a complete outsider I can't figure out the name from the logo so trying to complete it with a url is kind of pointless.

Comment: You may want to reconsider the thickness of your characters to make it a little more readable - personally I would make them thicker. Oh, and I don't like the drop shadows.

Comment: I think your concern is valid, but is more of a "consider going back to the drawing board" type of issue. Come up with some more ideas for the logo. This one is simply not as versatile as you need it to be.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a common practice to use different logos, but it is certainly something that you are seeing more with responsive design.

I often refer back to these articles about adapting logos for different screen sizes. It uses examples of some large companies and how they adapted their old, complicated logos for smaller screens.

http://www.logodesignlove.com/responsive-logos

https://www.viget.com/articles/responsive-logos-part-1-tips-for-adapting-logos-for-small-screens

Another fine example I came across last year by Mash Creative.

http://www.mashcreative.co.uk/project/dark-matter/

I personally have started creating logo variations for different purposes, but keeping 90% of the overall logo structure for ease of recognition. Uniformity is key.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the logo should work in all sizes, both large and small. However, if you've grown to really like your logo as it is now, you could consider to work a bit more with the elements, so you have the logo as is, but can "play" with combining the logo with a byline in different cases. One could say that you are also working with an "x-element" in the lines of "V" and "A".

I would suggest that you create different uses for the logo, on website, businesscard, letterhead, powerpoint or even on a cup or a pencil. The ask different people in your network what they think the logo is, and have them write 5-8 words that comes to mind when they see it. Then you'll know if it works, if people get it and also how it is perceived :)

To finish up here, I personally like no. 2 the most, but I'm not sure if the colors shown here are correct? If so, I would consider playing a bit more with the choices of color. Also, I would like to see the element "V" without round corners, but with sharp lines instead.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would stick with 1 or 2 versions at max. If you create multiple versions of your logo for different platforms / uses your customers, visitors etc. might get confused pretty quick as they might not be able to recognize your company that well.

Simple example. Company brand. Black panther.

What did you think of?

> Probably Nike.

Now imagine they would use more panthers depending how big their shoe is or the space available on their boxes. Companies have a good tactic with logos in general. They want your eye to remember a picture. And pictures are easier to remember than plain text. This is why knockoffs are sometimes so easy to spot, your eye sees a logo and goes

> Hey! I know tha- Hold up. Somethings not right here.

Because the shapes your eye sees are not conform with the ones in your memories.

My answer kinda went into marketing here and there, don't get my wrong, I like your idea to play with your logo, just think about this for a second before going head first into creation.

Comment: I have some ideas, opinions, ya know? It is fine to have several versions of a logo for different media, particularly for different sizes. The differences should only be in complexity. The favicon will be the simplest and you can only fit a couple letterforms.  The full screen size can be the fully detailed, shaded and finished one but it shouldn't have many elements that the simpler ones don't. Don't add www or dot com,  if it's a name or monagram of a company that has the same name in their website URL then let people figure it out.

Comment: The logo does not have to look like a link back to the site.   When I read your question and saw the first example I thought it was up/ down arrows, which is a great way to illustrate the concept of nav (maybe left/right arrows?).  I do not see the word nav in the other examples until you said it.  I don't see the shadows everyone has a problem with, unless they mean the blue fill. I think the proportion and stroke of your letterforms look good.

Comment: The blue fill is hard to understand and makes each V look like the star trek badge.  This is a great start and I would continue to work toward a solution that is a graphical representation of the concept "nav" either getting the whole word in there or use some of the common navigation symbols.